# How to partition Vec in place in method that doesn't own `self`?

Tags: rust

So, there's some struct that looks like this:

```
struct foo {
    alpha: Vec<T>,
    beta: Vec<T>,
}
```

And some method should move some values that matches some condition from `alpha` to `beta`. The question is: what is the clean way to do it without owning `self`?

The `Vec::partition()` method can't be used because any moving of `self.alpha` causes `cannot move out of dereference of &mut-pointer` compile error.

PS: `T` have `File` inside so it doesn't implement `Clone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to just drop `beta`? This is the sort of thing that [`std::mem::replace`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) is for, allowing you to pull it out:

```
use std::mem;

impl Foo {
    fn munge(&mut self) {
        let alpha = mem::replace(&mut self.alpha, Vec::new());
        let (alpha, beta) = alpha.partition(…);
        self.alpha = alpha;
        self.beta = beta;
    }
}
```

Note that there *is* a new `Vec` created there briefly, but that doesn’t really matter; it doesn’t involve an allocation and is very cheap. (The alternative would be leaving uninitialised memory there and replacing it again, forgetting the uninitialised memory, but that is unsafe if the partition can fail as it will run the destructor on the uninitialised memory.)

---

Since you want to just shift the elements matching the predicate, it’s worth looking at how `partition` is implemented:

```
pub fn partition<F>(self, mut f: F) -> (Vec<T>, Vec<T>) where F: FnMut(&T) -> bool {
    let mut lefts  = Vec::new();
    let mut rights = Vec::new();

    for elt in self.into_iter() {
        if f(&elt) {
            lefts.push(elt);
        } else {
            rights.push(elt);
        }
    }

    (lefts, rights)
}
```

Knowing that this is how it is implemented makes implementing something like it which doesn’t involve a second vector being created is rather easy; here’s the general idea:

```
let source = mem::replace(&mut self.alpha, Vec::new());
for element in source.into_iter() {
    if f(&element) { /* for some `f` */
        self.alpha.push(element)
    } else {
        self.beta.push(element)
    }
}
```

Really, `mem::replace` is the only thing you need to know about for these sorts of things; the rest then becomes fairly easy.

Comment: Nope, I don't want to drop `beta`. I want to push there values removed from `alpha`. But `std::mem::replace` looks really useful, thanks.